# How to scope a Database to a User using Dagger Hilt and Room?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-jetpack, dagger-hilt

I am trying to provide different databases based on their logged in User ID, so that each user can have its own database, should you login with a different account. I don't want to provide an "owner" field, I tried it and didn't liked it.

The problem right now is, that the Database is scoped to the Application Scope and is therefore not recreated once the user logs out and another one in. Only when restarting the app the correct database gets created.

How can I achieve such behaviour using Hilt?

This is how it looks right now:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ModuleDatabase {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        userManager: UserManager,
    ): MyRoomDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, MyRoomDatabase::class.java, LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME + "_${userManager.loggedInUid()}")
            .addMigrations(...)
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `@Named`  injection i guess. but i am not really Sure how that will turn out.

Comment: not entirely sure how this should work

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#multiple-bindings Check this . I think instead of `Qualifier` annotation you can use a `@Named` annotation with database name .  It will Still be a Singleton but it will created a instance against that database name  and lets say of log out and login with new user the the name will get changed and it will create a new Singleton instance of that DB . Its just a theory for now i never worked with multiple databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I need to create a custom Hilt Component that meets the requirements:

- https://dagger.dev/hilt/custom-components.html
- https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/hilt-adding-components-to-the-hierarchy-96f207d6d92d

(keep in mind that this will not work with WorkManager)

**UPDATE:** It actually works by avoiding Hilt Singleton scoping and just build it yourself. This also works with WorkManager because WorkManager can access dependencies inside SingletonComponents.

It basically works like this:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object ModuleDatabase {

    private var databaseName: String by Delegates.observable(LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME) { _, oldValue, newValue ->
        if (oldValue != newValue) {
            databaseConnection?.let {
                if (it.isOpen) {
                    it.close()
                }
                databaseConnection = null
                // new connection opens with new name
            }
        }
    }

    private var databaseConnection: TemporyRoomDatabase? = null

    private fun buildDatabase(context: Context, name: String): TemporyRoomDatabase {
        Timber.e("Building database $databaseName")
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context, TemporyRoomDatabase::class.java, name)
            .addMigrations(*TemporyRoomDatabase_Migrations.build())
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
    }

    private fun getDatabaseConnection(context: Context, newDatabaseName: String): TemporyRoomDatabase {
        return if (databaseName != newDatabaseName) {
            databaseName = newDatabaseName
            buildDatabase(context, databaseName).also {
                databaseConnection = it
            }
        } else {
            // use existing connection
            Timber.e("Reusing database $databaseName")
            databaseConnection ?: buildDatabase(context, databaseName)
        }
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideAppDatabase(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context,
        userManager: UserManager,
    ): TemporyRoomDatabase {
        return getDatabaseConnection(context, LOCAL_DATABASE_NAME + "_${userManager.loggedInUidOrNull()}")
    }
}
```